# How to solve CORS policy problem to Rest API in Ionic 4

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to consume an REST API (I don't have control over the backend API) in my IONIC application, but I having CORS problem during the request.
I'm using the HTTP Client to do request for API Rest and also I tried follow the documentation in ionic framework related to CORS error (https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/cors#cors-headers) using HTTP from '@ionic-native/http/ngx', but none of both implementation are working.
Could you please help me understand the how to fix this problem? follow below my implementation. thanks so much

Implementation using HTTP CLIENT:

```
private url = 'https://abcdefghijkl/8020/stats?sid=1&json=1'; //REST API

// Headers
private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'})
};

private constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private http: HTTP) {}

/**
 * Retrieves playing information
 *
 * @returns {Observable<any[]>}
 */
public getDataUsingHTTPClient(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url, this.httpOptions);
        /*.pipe(
            retry(2),
            catchError(this.handleError));*/
}

// Manipulação de erros
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // Client side error
        errorMessage = error.error.message;
    } else {
        // Server side error
        errorMessage = `Código do erro: ${error.status}, ` + `menssagem: ${error.message}`;
    }
    console.log(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
}
```

Implementation using HTTP from '@ionic-native/http/ngx'

```
public async getDataUsingHTTP() {
    try {
        const url = 'https://radion.jmhost.com.br/radio/8020/stats?sid=1&json=1';
        const params = {};
        const headers = {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'};

        const response = await this.http.get(url, null, headers);

        console.log(response);
        console.log(JSON.parse(response.data)); // JSON data returned by server
        console.log(response.headers);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.status);
        console.error(error.error); // Error message as string
        console.error(error.headers);
      }
}
```

Follow my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
import { AppAvailability } from '@ionic-native/app-availability/ngx';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
import { SocialSharing} from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {HTTP} from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    BackgroundMode,
    AppAvailability,
    InAppBrowser,
    SocialSharing,
    HTTP
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have access to backend side, I suggest you using https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http. This plugin bypasses CORS so you won't have any issues.

Ionic plugin is this one https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http. Use it instead of the Angular one.

Comment: As I said in my question I already use that, but it's not working, could you please check my second implementation that I put in my question. thanks

Comment: Sorry then, didn't fully understand you I guess, could you show the error that the plugin is throwing? @AndréRibeiro